# How to integrate Webview in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, browser, safari, webview

I am working in iPhone application, Using Webview to load Addvertisement in bottom of the screen and its working fine, i want to when the user select the WebView, its automatically goes to browser and load in iPhone device, How to integrate this? please help me

Thanks in Advance

I tried this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 430, 320, 50)];
[webView setDelegate:self];
NSString *urlAddress = @"http://www.dasfafa./myadds.html";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];
[self.view addSubview:webView];
}

-(void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView 
{

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
}

-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
    NSString *currentURL = self.AddvertiseWebView.request.URL.absoluteString;
    NSLog(@"currentURL:%@",currentURL);

}
```

Comment: Have you tried to add a link in the Ad that opens a new window in javascript?: window.open(URL,name,specs,replace)

Comment: can you put touchesBegan on the ad

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here code showing you how to open a link in Safari when clicked on in your UIWebView. The method shouldStartLoadWithRequest is a delegate method that is called when a link is clicked on. You can override the method and tell it to open in Safari.

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView 
     shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
     navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType; {

    NSURL *requestURL = [ [ request URL ] retain ]; 
    // Check to see what protocol/scheme the requested URL is.
    if ( ( [ [ requestURL scheme ] isEqualToString: @"http" ] 
        || [ [ requestURL scheme ] isEqualToString: @"https" ] ) 
        && ( navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked ) ) {
        return ![ [ UIApplication sharedApplication ] openURL: [ requestURL autorelease ] ]; 
    }
    // Auto release 
    [ requestURL release ];
    // If request url is something other than http or https it will open 
    // in UIWebView. You could also check for the other following 
    // protocols: tel, mailto and sms
    return YES;
}
```

or Try this

```
-(BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)inWeb shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)inRequest navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)inType {
    if ( inType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked ) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[inRequest URL]];
        return NO;
    }

    return YES; }
```

Comment: I tried your code, but the url load inside the WebView, but i want to load url in browser

Comment: review this link may be helped you..  http://ashiphone.blogspot.in/2011/02/create-third-party-ads-through-webview.html